Is there any issue with aioboto3 library in python?
I am using aioboto3 library in python for my python project which is built on fastapi, uvicorn and is managed using poetry .
For type checking I am using pyre check.
The problem I am running into this error while I am executing this command
poetry run pyre check
ERROR:

ƛ Found 1 type error!
personal_py/control/po_controller.py:2:0 Undefined import [21]: Could not find a module corresponding to import `aioboto3`.

I installed the aioboto3 and even in VSCode it is not showing me any error/warning at the import statement.
Furthermore, it is added to the pyproject.toml file too.
I do not know why it is showing as type error when all the configuration is done correctly.
These are the versions i am using in my project:


Does the version/enviornment of python you're running with (which python) match the version of python in VSCode?

yes the python version is the same .... since i have added it to my path variables and also the same is chosen as the Interpreter in VS Code
